# Avoiding thick rules in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, rules

This is my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|p{3.5cm}|X|X|}
some text & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{some text} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image: table with thick lines]

Is there a way to get rid of the thicker rule in the middle without removing one of the pipe symbols | in the table preamble or in the multicolumn command?

Comment: Change `|c|` -> `c|`

Comment: @daleif I have edited my question.

Comment: It is not a thick rule,  it's just  you have two normal rules next to each other; one induced by the first column and the other from `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}` (the  left rule).

Comment: @Bernard I know. Now the question is: is there a way to avoid the double rule?

Comment: Follow  @daleif indication: no left rule in `multicolumn`.

Comment: @Bernard So there is no way to set something like collapse border like in CSS?

Comment: I don't know CSS, so I don't see what you mean with ‘collapse border’. Superimpose both rules, perhaps?

Comment: except for the first column rules are only on the right so basically `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}` is an unreported syntax error. There are things you can do but all of them are more complicated than using `\multicolumn{2}{c|}`

Comment: So you need to know in advance (cell + 1) if there is a left border? There is no way around it? What a pity...

Answer (score 1):

I will give an alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. Firstly, it make a correct multicolumn cell which spans two `X` columns. Secondly, by using `\SetCell` command we don't need to worry about cell borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{@{}|t{3.5cm}|X|X|}
some text & \SetCell[c=2]{c} some text & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, the command `\Block` merges cells both vertically and horizontally and the rules (for instance specified by `|` in the preamble) are *not* drawn in the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{3.5cm}|X|X|}
some text & \Block{1-2}{some text} & \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]